# Add repo as your remote and cherry pick

Tags: git, cherry-pick

How to 
add this repo as a remote and cherry pick the incremental patches.
https://github.com/adridu59/semc-7x30-kernel-ics/commits/master-V2?page=6

I need update kernel for android only from this repo (not from other sites)

```
cd '/home/teru/android/system/kernel/semc/msm7x30'
git remote add zzz https://github.com/adridu59/semc-7x30-kernel-ics/commits/master-V2?page=6
git cherry-pick -n <commit>
```

(I know what enter to )
but have error

```
fatal: bad revision <commit>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are two problems. Firstly, the URL to the repo is incorrect--thats just a URL to somewhere on Github. Secondly, you need to fetch all of the commits from the remote after you add it.

So you should end up with something like this:

```
cd /home/teru/android/system/kernel/semc/msm7x30
git remote add zzz git://github.com/adridu59/semc-7x30-kernel-ics.git
git fetch zzz
git cherry-pick -n <commit>
```